# PHP: select the latest file added to an Amazon S3 folder

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm working on an auto-update solution, and I'm using Amazon S3 for distribution.

I would like for this to work like follows:

1. I upload a file to s3 folder
2. An automatic PHP script detects that a new file has been added and notifies clients

To do this, I somehow need to list all files in an amazon bucket's folder, and find the one which has been added last.

I've tried `$s3->list_objects("mybucket");`, but it returns the  list of all objects inside the bucket, and I don't see an option to list only files inside the specified folder.

What is the best way to do this using Amazon S3 PHP api?

Comment: That's because "folders" in S3 are not really folders. Why don't you just include the client-notification as part of the upload?

Comment: yes, this is also possible. Nevertheless, I'm still curious how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To do this, I somehow need to list all files in an amazon bucket's folder, and find the one which has been added last.

S3's API isn't really optimized for sort-by-modified-date, so you'd need to call `list_buckets()` and check each timestamp, always keeping track of the newest one until you get to the end of the list.

> An automatic PHP script detects that a new file has been added and notifies clients

You'd need to write a long-running PHP CLI script that starts with:

```
while (true) { /*...*/ }
```

Maybe throw an occasional `sleep(1)` in there so that your CPU doesn't spike so badly, but you essentially need to sleep-and-poll, looping over all of the timestamps each time.

> I've tried $s3->list_objects("mybucket");, but it returns the list of all objects inside the bucket, and I don't see an option to list only files inside the specified folder.

You'll want to set the `prefix` parameter in your [`list_objects()`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/list_objects) call.

Answer (score 0):

S3 launched versioning functionality of files in bucket http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html.

You could get latest n files by calling s3client.listVersions(request) and specifying n if you want.See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/list-obj-version-enabled-bucket.html

Example is in java. Not sure if the API for PHP is added for versioning.