# php s3 sdk - how to get object's latest version

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm trying to get latest version of a given object. I tried using this function `listObjectVersions` but couldn't get it to work like I want. It lists all the files, with their versions, on my bucket.

```
$fileVersion = $s3Client->listObjectVersions([
    'Bucket' => 'bucketname',
    'Key' => 'folder/file.jpeg' // get all versions of this file. though, this doesn't work
  ]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: select the latest file added to an Amazon S3 folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087414/php-select-the-latest-file-added-to-an-amazon-s3-folder)

Comment: I solved it by using `Prefix` instead of `Key` and in the versions array, first one is the latest version of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing objects in your buckets

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Prefix' => 'foo'
));

foreach ($iterator as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
}
```

More : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#listing-your-buckets